# removing double quote in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis-2012

I have a bunch of text documents which i need to import into a sql server table. However the values of the text file have a double quote " which i need to remove from all the text files. I was wondering what is the best way of doing this in SSIS using the foreach loop or any better way in SSIS?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
In your **FLAT FILE CONNECTION MANAGER EDIT**, 
you find tab [Text qualifier] where you can insert **"** 
more information [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140266.aspx)

Comment: can theat be used for removing "?

Comment: Yes, added link to help